# Changing Source Data for Excel table linked to SAS dataset

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I have an excel table linked to a SAS dataset using the SAS Office Addin.  I would like to modify the source (file path) of the data.

For example, right now the Excel table is linked to SAS Dataset: S:\SASdata1.sas7bdat

I would like to update the table to be linked to S:\SASdata2.sas7bdat

It seems like there would be some vba object in the SAS Add-In with a 'source' property that I could update.  But I haven't found one.

Comment: I would definitely post this on the SAS community forums - I'm not sure if anyone on SO of the usual crew uses EG not to mention the add-ins. EG folks are the majority over there, though.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a SAS View and update the same view to point to your second dataset?

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the "Connection Properties" in Excel here:
Data/Connections/Properties

and flip over to the "Definition" tab, you can edit the SAS file location in the "Command text".  I had the same problem as you, I think, and changing the table name in the command text worked perfectly for me.

Hopefully that works for others who may have this question in the future.  I realize this question was asked back in 2013...  :P

Sean